# Deploy PHP Files with Capistrano 3 to public_html instead of releases folder

Tags: php, capistrano3

I am new to Capistrano 3.
I want to deploy my php application to public_html folder (i'm using cPanel)

I setup my `deploy_to` something like this:
`set :deploy_to, '/home/username/public_html'`
And when i run:
`cap production deploy`
It's successfully upload to my server, but it deployed to `releases` and `current` folder instead to root directory which is `public_html`

My question is, how to make Capistrano upload to my public_html root folder?

Answer (score 1):

You will want to deploy to something like /home/username/code

Then you can create a symbolic link from /home/username/public_html to /home/username/code

The command would look like:

```
ln -s /home/username/code /home/username/public_html
```

Answer (score 1):

You can process by deploying files outside the public_html first, then symlink the current release to the public_html fodler as below:

1) In your **config/deploy.rb** or **config/deploy/****.rb** files set the **deploy_to** to be another folder outside the **public_html** like

`set :deploy_to , '/home/username/deploy'`

2) In your **config/deploy.rb** or **config/deploy/****.rb** files, add a variable with the path to the public_html

`set :public_html_path, '/home/username/public_html'`

3) Add a custom task **release_public_html** to symlink the public_html folder after the current release symlink is created

```
after "deploy:symlink:release", "deploy:symlink:release_public_html"

namespace :deploy do
  namespace :symlink do
    desc "Symlink release to current"
    task :release_public_html do
      on release_roles :all do
    public_html_path = "#{fetch(:public_html_path)}"
        execute :rm, "-rf", public_html_path
        execute :ln, "-s", current_path, public_html_path
      end
    end
  end
end
```